# Trouble with hardware encoding on OBS on Bay Trail

Tags: intel-graphics, obs-studio, vaapi

I've been having trouble for a while with OBS (repository, Flatpak, and Snap versions); only software H.264 encoding is exposed. vainfo shows the following info:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_6
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.7 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Bay Trail - 2.4.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
  VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
```

But I don't get either VA-API or QS encoding. I've tried changing my driver from i965-va-driver to i965-va-driver-shaders (propietary), but it hasn't changed anything. My CPU is an Intel® Celeron® N2806, and OBS works with hardware acceleration on Windows 8.1 using the Intel Quick Sync API. Thanks in advance.